# Error while installing snowflake connector for python

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to connect snowflake using python, I tried to install "Snowflake connector" for python using below command:
pip install snowflake-connector-python

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector.html

During installation I am facing following error:
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even I faced similar error while installing snowflake connector for python and I used below command and issue got resolved:

python3 -m pip install --no-use-pep517 snowflake-connector-python

Comment: on windows worked as ;
python -m pip install --no-use-pep517 snowflake-connector-python

Answer (score 1):

Python 3 I have no issue. Only with Python 2.7.

Try this if you are using python3. It is the documenation.

```
sudo python3 -m pip install setuptools-rust
sudo python3 -m pip install wheel
sudo python3 -m pip install -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/v2.3.9/tested_requirements/requirements_36.reqs
sudo python3 -m pip install snowflake-connector-python==2.3.9
```